# Null values in Redux Store, how do I clear it?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using the redux-persist library in my React Native app, meaning that of course, the state does not clear when the page is refreshed. The problem is that I somehow got a null value in that state, causing those `cannot read properties of null` errors in the Chrome console.

How do I reset the Redux store to the initial state?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that the easiest way to do this is to simply clear the browser cache. This will delete all persisted data.